# Access JSON key with forward slashes NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an object. In my object, there is a key with forward slashes and I would like to access the child of the key with forward slashes `pattern`

I have tried several approaches to no avail, please help with a solution to access the `pattern` property. Object is at the bottom

```
test.attributes./worker/workAssignment/homeOrganizationalUnits/typeCode/codeValue


SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
```

```
key = '/worker/workAssignment/homeOrganizationalUnits/typeCode/codeValue'
test.attributes.key


undefined
```

```
test.attributes.["key"]

Thrown:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

```
test.attributes.\/worker\/workAssignment\/homeOrganizationalUnits\/typeCode\/codeValue

Thrown:
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "/worker/workAssignment/homeOrganizationalUnits/typeCode/codeValue": {
            "pattern": "Department"
        }
    },
    "value": {
        "links": [{
            "href": "/codelists/hr/v3/worker-management/departments/WFN/1?$filter=foreignKey eq {payrollGroupCode}",
            "mediaType": "application/json",
            "method": "GET"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: `test.attributes[key]`

Comment: Sorry Chris, I don't think that is correct: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ex3Lwyqr/ (no dot before the square brackets)

Comment: Ah apologies, the key is to remove the `.` before referencing the variable in brackets. JS 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `'/'` character in the key name for object access as long as it is the value of a variable you use for the lookup.

```
var key = '///';
var obj = { '///': 'foo' };
obj[key];

> 'foo'
```

For more information, check out the MDN documentation on [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Answer (score 1):

Either `test.attributes[ key ]` or `test.attributes["/worker/workAssignment/homeOrganizationalUnits/typeCode/codeValue"]`, both are fine.